# Connecting to PC's localhost without wifi via USB

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging

I have a local server (XAMPP) on my PC. I'd like to test a local mobile site on that server. I do not have tethering as an option. At home, I can just use my local IP address and all works fine, but at work, that doesn't work. Somehow I'm on a separate subnet, and even if I force my device on the correct subnet, it still doesn't work, even though from my PC I can ping my droid.

So is there a way on my ICS tablet to plug into my computer via USB and through some setup, preferably without additional software, get to my localhost server?

Note: I also tried activating my mobile hotspot, and that didn't work either.

Comment: Just for clarification: you try to access your machine at home while being at work? And use the *local* address for that? I hope I got that wrong, as *this* cannot work.

Comment: @Izzy No, both devices are at work.

Comment: Presumably at work your phone is on a wifi network and your PC is on a wired network? You might want to check with your network admins whether the wifi network is fully trusted by wired devices, and if there's a firewall and/or NAT-ing happening between the two, as they might be blocking/preventing what you're trying.

Comment: @GAThrawn Tablet is on wifi. PC is on wifi. I work at a hotel, so no configurations are going to be changed. That's why I want to find a way to just do it without internet.

Comment: @David This bit "Somehow I'm on a separate subnet" sounds like known/trusted devices are being segregated from unknown/untrusted devices. We do this with our company wifi so that trusted devices can access the internal network and servers and untrusted ones can only access the internet. Someone in IT would need to add the phone to the trusted group to get round that, just changing your IP won't do anything useful, as the router knows which devices are which.

Comment: In the meantime, it sounds like you're trying to "reverse-tether" over USB, so you might find the answer looking through some of our [previous questions on that](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether+usb).

Comment: @GAThrawn there are no trusted devices on this network. As I said in my last post, I work at a hotel. I came across reverse tethering while searching for the answer to this before posting here, but, as I said in my original post, I don't have tethering as an option for my device.

Comment: @David your "mobile hotspot" is tethering (where a device gets internet connection through your phone) Reverse Tethering goes the other way,  your phone gets internet connection from another device, this is what you want. There are questions in the [tag:reverse-tether] where developers are trying to view websites hosted on a PC from an Android phone, my link in the comment above also [cross-referenced that with the USB tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether+usb) as reverse-tethering over a USB cable sounds like the easiest way for you to connect the two devices.